# Use of InSpec with Puppet

Tags: integration-testing, puppet, serverspec, inspec

I had been using ServerSpec for my integration testing with Chef.

Since ServerSpec is "deprecated" and InSpec is supported by Chef, I've change to use only InSpec, which is also supported in Puppet.

<del>However I'm not 100% sure is InSpec is the best tool for integration testing with Puppet. Is there a better or more recommended solution?</del>

How can I use inspec with Puppet?

Comment: InSpec is not supported in Puppet. Serverspec is supported in Beaker, which is supported by Puppet. I would definitely use ServerSpec over InSpec with Puppet. This is really an opinion-based question though.

Comment: I'm gonna rewrite the question since I realized that I could use Inspec with Puppet straight forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inspec is better than serverspec to do integration testing since it is more readable and helps to represent compliance as code. I use it with chef but Inspec is supported in puppet as well. You can refer the github [link](https://github.com/chef/inspec/tree/master/examples/kitchen-puppet) for examples

Comment: Inspec support remote execution straight forward, so if you are running/applying puppet with vagrant or in a remote server you can run the tests doing  `inspec exec *_spec.rb -t ssh://ubuntu@127.0.0.1:2222 --password 'xxxxx' --sudo`. You don't really need to install inspec in the remote server, only install inspec where your inspec code lives.